# How to Simplify the following divergent sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(n+1)^2}H_{n+k-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

The following double sum diverges.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(n+1)^2}H_{n+k-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

where $H_{n+k-1}$ denotes a Harmonic Number.

My only goal was to work towards something easier to manipulate namely convert it into a single sum or single integral.

I tried to let $$H_{n+k-1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^{n+k-1}}{1-x} $$
and work from there but got really weird results. Mathematica does not help much.

So my question is : how can i turn this double sum into a single sum or integral?

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Comment: May I ask why are you solving this sum?

Comment: @Editprofileandsettings this sum together with 2 other double sums converges, i was hoping that understanding one of them would aid me with the others since they are similar.